# How I could get integers from resources properly?

Tags: android, xml, android-resources

I'm strugling with getting results from the resourses in Android. I don't know if I'm doing wrong or if it can't be done.

I get the int in the logcat(debuggin because my code doesn't work). It is stored in a vector, I get that number for an if condition but it doesn't get the declared integer in resources.

```
        Log.d("Valor de int correcto",String.valueOf((int) puntuation.get(5)));
```

And the Log cad shows

> D/Valor de int correcto: 2131230722

The vector gets the int from...

```
puntuation.add(R.integer.c_1);
```

which is declared as:

> ```
> <integer name="c_1">1</integer>
> ```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use

```
puntuation.add(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.c_1));
```

Comment: getResources() method is deprecated @Jyoti Jk

Comment: @HiteshSarsava getResources() method is not deprecated